# Showing unwanted error while exception handling

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, exception, error-handling

Below is my code. I have written the exception but the output I am getting is the message printed and additional things which I have not passed

```
def put_object(key, document):
    logger.debug('Pushing to target bucket')
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')

    try:
        final_response = s3.put_object(Bucket='bucket_name', Key=key,
                                                Body=document)
        logger.debug(final_response)
        return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'body': 'Submitted in the S3 bucket'
        }
    except Exception as e:
        print("=====Bucket does not exist====", e)
```

and my output is coming like below

```
=====Bucket does not exist==== An error occurred (NoSuchBucket) when calling the PutObject operation: The specified bucket does not exist
```

I just want to print "=====Bucket does not exist====" nothing else.

Comment: If you only want to print that literal text and not the error, why are you passing `e` to `print`? Just do `print("=====Bucket does not exist====")`

Comment: I am able to get it now but why I am getting StackTrace ? How can I remove that?